# mysql how to fill a table with values ("scores") dependent on values in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple data tables on cities in a database in MYSQL and I would like to evaluate each dataset, and fill in columns with "scores" based on binning values in other tables.

So I have city_gas_prices and city_GDPs to start. I want to create a new table city_scores, where column 1 is city name, column 2 is gas_price_score, column 3 is GDP_score,

where city_scores.gas_price_score = 1 if city_gas_prices.gas_price is between 1.5 and 2, gas_price_score=2 if city_gas_prices.gas_price is between 2 and 2.5, gas_price_score=3 if city_gas_prices.gas_price is between 2.5 and 3

and where city_scores.GDP_score= 1 if city_GDPs.GDP is between 2 and 3, city_scores.GDP_score= 2 if city_GDPs.GDP is between 3 and 4, etc.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You did not specify if values are inclusive in the range. Anyway see my answer and improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the CASE WHEN conditions

```
SELECT cgp.city_ID AS CityID,
CASE 
  WHEN cgp.gas_price>=1.5 and cgp.gas_price<2 THEN 1
  WHEN cgp.gas_price>=2 and cgp.gas_price<=2.5 THEN 2
END AS gas_price_score,
CASE 
  WHEN cgdp.GDP>=2 and cgp.GDP<3 THEN 1
  WHEN cgdp.GDP>=3 and cgp.city_ID<=4 THEN 2
END AS GDP_score   
FROM city_gas_prices cgp
INNER JOIN city_GDPs cgdp
on cgp.city_ID=cdgp.cityID
```

Comment: I have marked it but looks like I cannot upvote because I am a new user.

Comment: that is fine. Glad i could help :)